# Mysql native spatial functions with sequelize and node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm storing a location of type POINT in my mysql database:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Promotion = sequelize.define('promotion', {
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    location: {
      type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT'),
      allowNull: false
    }
```

It looks like the point is being stored correctly:
[image]

I'm trying find all rows within a set of bounds using the mysql native `ST_MakeEnvelope` function. I was using this with postgresql and it worked perfectly, but when I switch to mysql it start throwing errors:

```
  if (northEastLng &&
      northEastLat &&
      southWestLat &&
      southWestLng)
  {
    where.location = {
      $overlap: db.sequelize.fn('ST_MakeEnvelope', southWestLng, southWestLat, northEastLng, northEastLat)
    }

  }

  promotion.findAll({
      where,
    })
    .then(promoters => {
      res.json(promoters)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('ERROR: ', err)
    })
```

The error:

```
Error: ER_WRONG_PARAMCOUNT_TO_NATIVE_FCT: 
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ST_MakeEnvelope'
```

So I tried passing in two points instead:

```
const POINT_ONE = `POINT(${southWestLng} ${southWestLat})`
const POINT_TWO = `POINT(${northEastLng} ${northEastLat})`
where.location = {
   $overlap: db.sequelize.fn('ST_MakeEnvelope', POINT_ONE, POINT_TWO)
}
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: 
Geometry byte string must be little endian.
```

Been searching around, and not too sure where to go from here. How do I use the `ST_MakeEnvelope` function with sequelize to query?

*Edit*

Adding the generated sql from piotrbienias response:

```
SELECT `promotion`.`id`, `promotion`.`userId`, `promotion`.`title`, `promotion`.`description`, `promotion`.`startDate`, `promotion`.`endDate`, `promotion`.`isIndefinite`, `promotion`.`isApproved`, `promotion`.`status`, `promotion`.`reach`, `promotion`.`trustRanking`, `promotion`.`isLocationBased`, `promotion`.`address`, `promotion`.`city`, `promotion`.`state`, `promotion`.`zip`, `promotion`.`location`, `promotion`.`createdAt`, `promotion`.`updatedAt`, `promotion`.`categoryId
`, `promotionImages`.`id` AS `promotionImages.id`, `promotionImages`.`url` AS `promotionImages.url`, `promotionImages`.`publicId` AS `promotionImages.publicId`, `promotionImages`.`secureUrl` AS `promotionImages.secureUrl`, `promotionImages`.`isApproved` AS `promotionImages.isApproved`, `promotionImages`.`createdAt` AS `promotionImages.createdAt`, `promotionImages`.`updatedAt` AS `promotionImages.updatedAt`, `promotionImages`.`promotionId` AS `promotionImages.promotionId`, `category`.`id` AS `cat
egory.id`, `category`.`title` AS `category.title` FROM `promotions` AS `promotion` LEFT OUTER JOIN `promotionImages` AS `promotionImages` ON `promotion`.`id` = `promotionImages`.`promotionId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `categories` AS `category` ON `promotion`.`categoryId` = `category`.`id` WHERE `promotion`.`location` && ST_MakeEnvelope(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-80.30252222253421 25.802030960352745)'), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-80.30252222253421 25.802030960352745)'));
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think that you should try other approach with use of `ST_Contains` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Geometry part of MySQL, but shouldn't you use the `ST_GeomFromText` function on those points before using them?

```
where.location = {
    $overlap: db.sequelize.fn(
            'ST_MakeEnvelope',
            db.sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', POINT_ONE),
            db.sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', POINT_TWO),
        )
    }
};
```

Just as it is presented in the example of [`ST_MakeEnvelope`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-makeenvelope) function (and it takes two parameters, so that may be the reason of your first error `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ST_MakeEnvelope'`). And, as I said on the beginning, I am definitely not an expert in these, just my suggestion after taking a look at the MySQL documentation.

**EDIT**

Below is description of `$overlap` from Sequelize documentation

> $overlap: [1, 2]       // && [1, 2] (PG array overlap operator)

I think that you should construct your Sequelize query differently, without the `$overlap`. I suppose that you should use `ST_Contains` function and your `where` object should be as follows

```
{
    where: db.sequelize.where(
        db.sequelize.fn(
            'ST_Contains',
            db.sequelize.fn(
                'ST_MakeEnvelope',
                db.sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', POINT_ONE),
                db.sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', POINT_TWO)
            ),
            db.sequelize.col('promotion.location')
        ),
        '=',
        1
    )
}
```

In my opinion the SQL you want should be something like:

```sql
WHERE ST_Contains(POLYGON(...), location)
```

Above Sequelize query would generate

```sql
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_MakeEnvelope(ST_GeomFromText(POINT_ONE), ST_GeomFromText(POINT_TWO)), location) = 1;
```

Which should check if polygon created from two points contains value of `location` column. [`ST_Contains`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains) returns 1 or 0, so I think that `= 1` condition should be ok in this case.

Comment: Got rid of the errors. But it's not returning any results

Comment: Does it generate proper sql?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it. I posted the generated sql on my the bottom of my post. The envelope portion is at the end of the sql